# Downvoted by removed user

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I noticed today that I was downvoted. In the explanation, it simply says, 'User was removed.' I assume this has something to do with spamming or abuse or something. Shouldn't that downvote be removed, as well?

[image]

Comment: That's not a downvote, it's the removal of a question upvote following an account deletion.